# Serialize an input-map into string

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a generic serilization function in clojure. Something Like this

```
(def input-map {:Name "Ashwani" :Title "Dev"})
(defn serialize [input-map delimiter]
...rest of the code
)
```

Which when called

```
(serialize input-map ",") Produces 
Ashwani,Dev
```

I have some thing as of now which needs specific keys of the map but does this

```
(defn serialize [input-map]
  (map #(str (% :Name) "," (% :Title) "\n") input-map ) )
```

What I want to avoid is the hardcoding Name and title there. There must be some way to use reflection or something to accomplish this but unfortunately I dont know enough clojure to get this done.

Comment: I am confused by how you are using "serialize". Generally serialize implies the ability to reconstruct the data from the output but you aren't saving the keys at all.  Also if you want the function to be generic but not output the keys themselves you will still need to provide the keys to the function so that you can control the order in which they output.

Comment: @Alex - The answer below from overthink does what I need and the question that I wrote clearly demostrate what I want to achieve. If you have a problem with "Serliaze" word lets call it "Foo"..

Comment: My apologies, my previous comment clearly came across as overly critical which is a common failing of mine. My intent was to help prompt a clearer question in case you didn't get the answer you needed. If you got what you needed then great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
(require 'clojure.string)
(defn serialize [m sep] (str (clojure.string/join sep (map (fn [[_ v]] v) m)) "\n"))
(def input-map {:Name "Ashwani" :Title "Dev"})
(serialize input-map ",")
```

yields

```
"Ashwani,Dev\n"
```

Not sure how idiomatic this is, but it should work for you.

**Update:** [Julien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679757/serialize-an-input-map-into-string/6682683#6682683) is way nicer than mine!  `vals` ... how could I miss that :)

Answer (score 7):

```
(defn serialize [m sep] (apply str (concat (interpose sep (vals m)) ["\n"])))
```

Answer (score 4):

It is quit simple.

```
(str input-map)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Normal" clojure types can be serialized using pr-str and re-instated using read-string. Unless you've got a reason to format your serialized data in the specific way you described, I'd suggest using pr-str instead if only because its output is more readable.

Comment: I have a list of maps and I want to get the values from them and write to a CSV file so the above approach is what I need but applythis on defstruct is giving me error as of now..